# What's the 20000th word in Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious?

Tags: permutations, combinations

If all the words made from the letter of the word **Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious** (with and without meaning) are arranged in the sequence as supposed to be in a dictionary, then what is the $20,000$th letter in that sequence, is there any simple method to find it?

By calculation I found that there are total $$\frac{34!}{3!\ 2!\ 3!\ 2!\ 2!\ 2!\ 3!\ 2!\ 7!} = 84{,}74{,}81 {,} 71 {,} 75 {,} 54 {,} 71 {,} 31 {,} 65 {,} 18 {,} 66 {,} 62 {,} 40 {,} 00 {,} 000\ \text{words possible}$$ $$\approx84 \times 10^{29}\ \text{words}$$
So finding rank of a *first word too is headache!* Any simpler method to find it out!

Comment: How many of the words begin with $a$?  How many with $c$?  In this way, figure out the first letter.   then the first two letters. And so on.

Comment: What does "finding rank of a *first word*" mean? The first word is clearly aaaccceefgiiiiiiillloopprrssstuu.

Comment: Note:  I don't know what you mean by the $n^{th}$ *letter*.  Do you mean the $n^{th}$ *word*?  If you really mean letter, I guess you ought to divide by the number of letters to get the relevant word number.

Comment: From your count, it seems you want the words which use **all** the letters of the word, and does not contain shorter words, like “super.”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes by using all the letters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a correction; the number of distinct words consisting of precisely these $34$ letters is
$$\frac{34!}{1!^52!^53!^47!^1}=1412469529257855275311104000000.$$
Assuming you are only listing words that use all letters, each word has $34$ letters. So the $20000$th letter is the $8$th letter of the $589$th word, because
$$20000=34\times589+8.$$
The number $589$ is not very big; we already get $589$ words from just permuting the last couple of letters. For example, the number of permutations of the segment $rrssstuux$ is already
$$\frac{9!}{1!^22!^23!^1}=15120.$$
This means the first $15120$ words all start with the same segment
$$aaacccdeefgiiiiiiillloopp.$$
In particular the $8$th letter of the $589$th word is $e$.

Comment: Lee Mosher's comment omitted the letters 'd' and 'x'.

Comment: @DanielMathias I have corrected my answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @Servaes So you have written $20000 = 34 \times 589 + 8$, so it can have other forms too! The different forms of these notation would also give same answer? right?